# How to use @Qualifier or @Named with @AfterMapping in mapstruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct

In their documentation (here: http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/api/org/mapstruct/AfterMapping.html), they mention that @AfterMapping can be used with @Qualifier / @Named to filter, but I can't find it anywhere how to actually use it this way.

My best guess was to use it like this:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class CustomerMapper {

    @Named("Test")
    public abstract Customer map(CustomerDto dto);

    @Named("Test")
    @AfterMapping
    public void doAfterMapping(@MappingTarget Customer customer) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

But that seems to do nothing (If I remove the @Named annotations it works, but it is also used in other methods, which I don't want).. Does anyone know how this needs to be used?

Answer (score 16):

I got help in their gitter chatrooms, if anyone is looking for the same thing, this is doable with @BeanMapping like this:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class CustomerMapper {

    @BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = "Test")
    public abstract Customer map(CustomerDto dto);

    @Named("Test")
    @AfterMapping
    public void doAfterMapping(@MappingTarget Customer customer) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed. Since this method applies to the entire beanmappingmethod and not to an individual property you need to add a @BeanMapping annotation.