# MapStruct: How can I filter which after-mapping method to use?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have written a MapStruct mapper which has two methods with the `@AfterMapping` annotation. Depending on the context, I want only one of these methods to be executed before the end of the mapping. 
 
With regard to this, the [MapStruct documentation](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/api/org/mapstruct/AfterMapping.html) states:

> All after-mapping methods that can be applied to a mapping method will
>   be used. `@Qualifier / @Named` can be used to filter the methods to use.

Regarding `@Named`, the documentation contains a [good example](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/api/org/mapstruct/Named.html) on how to use this annotation in order to perform two different kinds of mappings for a bean property. But I do not understand how to adapt this kind of distinction to my two after-mapping methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the qualifier in the @BeanMapping annotation in order to make it applicable to life cycle method. Note: I recently fixed an issue in this area on the master. Don't think that's released already. Forgot the exact issue (not able to look it up currently)

Comment: I think I found an example for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746320/how-to-use-qualifier-or-named-with-aftermapping-in-mapstruct?rq=1.